# Attribute as result of function has empty property value?

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Rtti;

function GetPropertyValue(const AObject: TObject; APropertyName: string): TValue;
var
  oType: TRttiType;
  oProp: TRttiProperty;
begin
  oType := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AObject.ClassType);
  if oType <> nil then
  begin
    oProp := oType.GetProperty(APropertyName);
    if oProp <> nil then
      Exit(oProp.GetValue(AObject));
  end;
  Result := TValue.Empty;
end;

function GetAttributePropertyValue(const AClass: TClass; AAttribute: TClass;
  AAttributePropertyName: string): TValue;
var
  oAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  for oAttr in TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AClass).GetAttributes do
    if oAttr.InheritsFrom(AAttribute) then
      Exit(GetPropertyValue(oAttr, AAttributePropertyName));
  Result := nil;
end;

function GetClassAttribute(const AClass: TClass; AAttribute: TClass): TCustomAttribute;
begin
  for Result in TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AClass).GetAttributes do
    if Result.InheritsFrom(AAttribute) then
      Exit;
  Result := nil;
end;

type
  DescriptionAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    FDescription: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const ADescription: string);
    property Description: string read FDescription;
  end;

constructor DescriptionAttribute.Create(const ADescription: string);
begin
  FDescription := ADescription;
end;

type
  [Description('MyClass description')]
  TMyClass = class(TObject);

var
  oAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  { ok, output is 'MyClass description' }
  WriteLn(GetAttributePropertyValue(TMyClass, DescriptionAttribute, 'Description').AsString);
  { not ok, output is '' }
  oAttr := GetClassAttribute(TMyClass, DescriptionAttribute);
  WriteLn(DescriptionAttribute(oAttr).Description);
  // WriteLn(oAttr.ClassName); // = 'DescriptionAttribute'
  ReadLn;
end.
```

I need the rtti attribute. I was hoping to get attribute with function `GetClassAttribute()` but the result is not expected.

Result of function `GetAttributePropertyValue()` is correct (first WriteLn), but result of function `GetClassAttribute()` is DescriptionAttribute with empty Description value. Why?

What is correct way to get attribute as function result ?

TIA and best regards
Branko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that all RTTI related objects created during querying information (including attributes) are being destroyed if the TRttiContext goes out of scope.

You can verify this when you put a destructor on your attribute class.

Recent versions introduced `KeepContext` and `DropContext` methods on `TRttiContext` you can use or just put a global variable somewhere and cause it to trigger the internal creation by calling `Create` or something. I usually put the `TRttiContext` variable as class variable into the classes using RTTI.

`KeepContext` and `DropContext` can be used in code where you might not have one global `TRttiContext` instance that ensures its lifetime because you are using other classes, methods and routines that have their own `TRttiContext` reference - see for instance its use in `System.Classes` where during `BeginGlobalLoading` `KeepContext` is being called and in `EndGlobalLoading` `DropContext`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the use of KeepContext() and DropContext(). Please explain how to use this in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer.  And sorry but I can't upvote twice ;)